# Recursive function calculating average from int array three by three elements

Tags: c, recursion

Calculating average three by three elements and replacing those elements with the average result.

Example array `[1,2,7,-2,5,0, 2,8]`
After transformation `[3,3,3,1,1,1,5,5]`

Something is wrong, I can't get it to work.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( )    {
    int n, c[n];
    int *avg;
    int pom=0;

    printf("Enter lenght of array\n");

    scanf("%d",&n);

    printf("Enter elements");

    for(i = 0;i < n; i++)
        scanf("%d",c[i]);

    avg=Average(c , n, pom);

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("Avg elements= %d",*(avg+i))
    return 0;
}

int Average(int arr[], int size, int z)
{
    int k, l, m, Asum;

    if (size < 0) {
        return arr;
    } else {
        k=arr[z];
        l=arr[z+1];
        m=arr[z+2];

        Asum=(k + l + m)/3;

        arr[z]=Asum;
        arr[z+1]=Asum;
        arr[z+2]=Asum;
    }

    return Average(arr,size--,z++);
}
```

Comment: Indent the code by 4 spaces to make the code look like code.

Comment: @Lolapanza, I edited your code, but pay attention; without proper indentation people won't even start reading your questions.

Comment: @Lolapanza So, what is the question here?

Comment: @Lolapanza select your code and press `ctl`+`k`

Comment: @Tarc Thank you Tarc. I am kind of new here, don't know how to edit code yet. Thanks for the tip .

Comment: @PeterG. I can't seem to get it working...

Comment: I removed Whitespace and corrected the braces in the if/else, hopefully that wasn't the error?

Comment: @PeterG. Thank you Peter. that shouldn't be the error something else probably is , put i can't seem to put my finger on it..

Comment: the posted code does not cleanly compile.   strongly suggest enabling all warnings when compiling, then fix the warnings.   Some of the warnings are very serious, like the average function is missing a prototype before the main function.  This means the compiler will make assumptions about the average function that are not correct.  for gcc, at a minimum use: '-Wall -Wextra -pedantic'

Comment: 1) the 'i' variable is not defined.  2) implicit declaration of function 'Average'  3) this line: 'avg=Average(c , n, pom);' makes pointer from integer without a cast  4) this line: 'printf("Avg elements= %d",*(avg+i))' is missing trailing semicolon ';'

Comment: the line: 'int c[n];' will not properly compile until after the value of 'n' is known.  suggest moving this variable declaration to after the call to scanf() for the value of 'n'

Comment: this line: 'return arr;' will return the address of arr[], not a sum/average.  2) the scanf for variable 'n' should use an unsigned format specifier, so no negative number can be entered.   the recursive call to Average() is not correct, as it keeps sending the same value parameters.  I.E. the parameters should be predecrement and preincrement, not postdecrement and postincrement.

Comment: for readability/understandability, place only 1 variable declaration per line.  This also makes it easy to properly comment the variables as to their purpose, which will be a requirement when you get into the 'real world'.

Comment: if number of elements is not a multiple of 3, then the last pass through the recursion will be accessing memory past the end of arr[].  This is undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event

Comment: in the recursion call, the offsets into the array 'z' and the 'size' value need to be modified by 3 to step past the array values that have already been processed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try simple input first, imagine what happens when you enter only 1 number, what will the Average function do? Don't run the code but try to execute it in your head or with pencil and paper. If you think the program only has to work with three or more numbers, try three.

A serious program would explicitly reject invalid input.

Answer (score 2):

`int n, c[n];` is a problem.  `n` is uninitialized so the size of the array is who-knows-what?  This is undefined behavior.

Instead

```
int main(void) {
  int n;
  int *avg;
  int pom=0;

  printf("Enter length of array\n");
  if (scanf("%d",&n) != 1) return -1;
  int c[n];

  for(i = 0;i < n; i++)
    // scanf("%d",c[i]);
    scanf("%d",&c[i]);  // pass the address of an `int`
```

Likely other issues too.

Comment: Thanks chux, didn't see that. What other issues?

Comment: @Lolapanza `if (size < 0) {` --> `if (z +3 < size) {` comes to mind else code is accessing outside the array.  The goal of `Average()` needs more definition, examples and corner cases.  @peter answer gives good advice.